# Sequelize addIndex on BLOB Field

Tags: indexing, sequelize.js

I'm using v6 of Sequelize with mariaDB. When I try to execute the following in a migrate file:

```
return queryInterface.addIndex('RVersion', ['terms'], {
   indicesType: 'FULLTEXT'
});
```

I get the following error message:

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'terms' used in key specification without a key length
```

What is the correct way to create this index in sequelize?

Comment: How should it look like in SQL?

Comment: ALTER TABLE RVersion ADD INDEX RVersion_terms (terms(255));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fields` option in options instead of the second parameter like this:

```js
return queryInterface.addIndex('RVersion', {
   fields: [{
     name: 'terms',
     length: 255
   }],
   type: 'FULLTEXT' // this option name is `type`
});
```